# Hadoop. Wordcount with statistic

Tags: java, hadoop

Ok. I have completed **wordcount** hadoop-program. But how I can calculate statistic (which word used most times, which average times and which word minimum times used)?

Is I need to make several **reducers**?

Sorry. Just I'm new in Hadoop, but for me this very interesting.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question, but I'll point you in the direction of [this book](http://lintool.github.io/MapReduceAlgorithms/).

I'll give a hint at the trick to the first question: You can output a sentinel value for each word (in the form of a `(*,word)` pair, for example) and then use a reduce phase to take each `(*,word)` (partitioned so that you only look at the second element of the tuple) to the number of times it appears.

You can then use the rest of the hadoop machinery (in particular changing the sort order) more or less, as a variant on the previous technique to get you most of the way there.